# No columns returned SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am implementing a SSIS package and currently trying to do the following.

1. Truncate the destination table
2. Fetch the data by executing the stored procedure and insert it into the destination table.

I have created an Execute SQL task to address step 1 and dataflow with oledb source and oledb destination to address the second point. It been working successfully so far but isn't working for one my stored procedure that uses temp tables.

When I edit the oledb source and click the preview button, I get the error no column returned

I know that SSIS has an issue with generating column while executing stored procedures that depend on temp tables. I have converted the stored proc to use temporary table variables and its now able to return columns in SSIS when I do a preview. The only downside is that the stored procedure is taking longer time to execute. Its taking 1 hour 15 mins as compared to 15 mins while using temp tables.

I did see a suggestion to use SET FMTONLY before executing the stored procedure as an alternate solution to changing to temp table variables but that didn't seem to work as I am getting syntax or permission denied error.

Could somebody tell me a solution to my problem which does not compromise on the performance.

Comment: Which version of SQL server is the SP using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've already read all the approaches to using Temp tables in SSIS, including the `IF 1=0...` trick?   If you haven't seen that one yet, google it.

You say that using Table Variables causes your stored procedure to take about 5 times longer than using Temp Tables.   The most likely reason for that is that you are indexing your temp tables but not your table variables. If you didn't know that table variables can be indexed, they can.  You might try that.

Finally, a solution that you haven't mentioned is that you can replace your temporary table with a real table that gets truncated when you're done using it.

Comment: Thanks Tab for your inputs,  I tried the 1=0. It internally tells SSIS to invoke  SET FMTONLY  ON and eventually I get the same error as I mentioned above. I tried the temp variables and it seems to be very slow. I am now trying physical table and shall update you shortly

Comment: The physical tables are taking a lot of time too. I have created the same indexes like I did for temp tables. Not sure why

Comment: Check the execution plan using the real tables and see if your indexes are being used.   Also what is the exact error you get with the 1=0 trick?

Comment: Hey Tab. Issue sorted. I just noticed that there was an index missing on of the tables and it executes fast now.

Answer (score 0):

Short comment:

Try EXEC WITH RESULT SETS and specify the metadata yourself for a proc with temp tables; or use the Script Component as a source and specify the Output columns yourself.

Long comment:

Technically speaking, it is the driver/database you are using in SSIS that would decide the behavior when working with temp tables.

Metadata is an important factor when using SSIS's pipeline components. By metadata, I mean the names of the columns, their data types etc that a pipeline component uses. When designing a data flow, someone/something should provide this metadata to the components that require it.

In most cases, SSIS automatically retreives the metadata. Components that do not connect to a external data source, like Conditional Split etc, get their metadata from the other components they are connected to. For the pipeline components that connect to a external data source (like Oledb source, oledb destination, Lookup etc.), SSIS provides a mechanism to get this metadata without human involvement. This mechanism involves the driver connecting to the database and retrieving the metadata of the output. If the driver/database is capable of returning the metadata, then that metadata is used. If the driver/database is incapable, then you get the errors you are seeing. The rest of my comments are based on the assumption that you are using a SQL Server database in your question.

When working with a SQL Server database in SSIS, typically, we use the native client drivers provided by Microsoft. When trying to get the metadata, these drivers try to get the metadata without actually executing the SQL Statement (actual execution can have side effects; and also, might take more than a few seconds/minutes/hours; and you dont want side effects and long wait times during package design time.) So to get the metadata, the driver relies on the metadata of the actual objects used in the sql command. If the command uses a physical table or view, SQL Server already has the metadata available and can supply it to the driver. If it is a temp table, SQL Server does not have the metadata until it can create the temp table. If using FMT ONLY option, you can use it in such a way to create the temp tables, but avoid any heavy processing/side affects and thus be able to retrieve metadata without penalties. Post 2012, these native client drivers rely on some newer functionality to retrieve metadata than the drivers before 2012. In 2012 and after, the driver uses the sp_describe_first_result_set proc to retrieve metadata. So, whether you can get metadata or not is determined by the ability of the sp_describe_first_result_set proc.

So while SSIS can automatically get the metadata (because of the driver/database), it does not automatically get the metadata in some cases (again because of the driver/database). In cases involving the second scenario, some other process (typically a human) can help the driver infer metadata or provide the metadata to the component directly.

To help the driver, in case of SQL Server 2012 and after, you can use the WITH RESULTSETS clause to specify the output metadata. When this clause is present, the driver will use it and doesnt try to query the metadata from system objects; and thus avoid the error which you would otherwise get. If you are using the drivers that came with SQL Server 2008, you can use FMT ONLY. This option is at the driver/database level.

Another option could be to use a Script Component as the Source and in the Output columns, you can specify the columns/metadata. SSIS would not try to retrieve metadata from the datasource in this case, but would rely on the definitions you provided in the Output section of the Script Component.

As you can see, both options involve a human (or some other process) specifying the metadata instead of SSIS trying to retrieve the metadata in an automated fashion. I would prefer the first option if working with SQL Server and the second option if working with databases like MySql.